# mathematica 8 densityhistogram label/display values

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, histogram, label

I'm trying to make a Density Histogram in Mathematica 8 that overlays the histogram values for each location.  What I want is for the value of each square to be displayed over it always (i.e. not in the Status Bar or as a Tool Tip).  For instance, if you run this code in Mathematica, one of the squares will have a value of 23, and I'd like that value overlaid on that square, and then the same for all the other non-zero values (I don't need a bunch of 0's).

```
a = {{1.6, 314.1592}, {0.8, 63.6172}, {0.4, 113.0973}, {1, 19.6349}, 
{1, 19.6349}, {1, 50.2654}, {1, 490.8738}, {1, 19.6349}, {0.045, 17.5}, 
{0.3, 80}, {0.06, 120}, {1, 100}, {1,78.5398}, {0.06, 120}, {1, 7.0685}, 
{0.33, 126.6768}, {1, 369.8361}, {0.0008, 0.09}, {1, 1134.1149}, {0.06, 64}, 
{0.08, 120}, {1, 113.0973}, {0.19, 600}, {1, 283.5287}, {0.00217,14}, 
{1, 201.0619}, {0.64, 283.5287}, {2, 1520.5308}, {60, 31.4159}, {0.3, 10}, 
{1, 201.0619}, {1, 283.5287}, {2, 12.5663}, {1, 506.7074}, {0.35, 176.7145}, 
{0.05, 1.1309}, {2, 1520.5308}, {0.7, 28.2743}, {1, 49}, {1, 100}, {1, 706.8583}, 
{1, 706.8583}, {8, 3848.451}, {1, 50.2654}, {1, 50.2654}, {1, 314.1592}, 
{1, 314.1592}, {1, 314.1592}, {1, 314.1592}, {1, 1140.0918}, {2, 314.1592}, 
{2, 314.1592}, {1.5, 314.1592}, {1, 23.7582}, {1, 15.2053}, {0.02, 0.415}, 
{1.5, 314.1592}, {1, 254.469}, {0.02, 0.415}, {1, 346.3605}, {0.5, 254.469}, 
{1, 95.0331}};

DensityHistogram[a, {
{{.0001, .001, .01, .1, 1, 10, 100}}, {{.01, .1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000}}},    
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors"][1 - #] &), 
  ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Thin], 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
  Method -> {"DistributionAxes" -> "Histogram"}, 
  Ticks -> {Table[{10^k, Superscript[10, k]}, {k, -4, 4}], 
  Table[{10^k, Superscript[10, k]}, {k, -2, 4}]},
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
  Mesh -> True, ImageSize -> 600, LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#1, Above] &)]
```

I'm not sure if I'm using LabelingFunction correctly, probably not.  I'd also like to see the relevant values on the axes histograms, if possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It may be the case that DensityHistogram doesn't fully support LabelingFunction (I played with it and couldn't get anywhere either)- you should ask on mathematica.stackexchange.com .

Comment: I'll try that, thanks!  I'll leave this one up just in case.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39502/densityhistogram-label-display-values-in-mathematica-8